# How to use as int, the result of a count on a view , using entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, casting, count

I want to use the result of my count :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS nbMailJour, id
FROM  dbo.t_mail
WHERE (CAST(dateEnvoi AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
GROUP BY id
```

In my entity application :

```
if (ctx.t_horaires.Any(p => (p.jours == x)
                             && (p.debut < y)
                             || ctx.v_mailsDuJour> 400)
```

I tried to cast it `(int)` and `convert.toint32()` but error.

I use a stored procedure

```
USE [DevotoCRM]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[nbrMail]    Script Date: 28/03/2014 09:48:21         ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[nbrMail]
    @dateMail DATE ,
    @nbrDeMailDuJour INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT COUNT(*)  
FROM t_mail 
WHERE CAST (dateEnvoi AS DATE) = CAST ( @dateMail AS DATE);
END
```

So when I want to get back thr output value of my procedure, it throw an error,

```
int? a = (int?)ctx.nbrMail(DateTime.Now);
```

Error : 
"Erreur 7 Impossible de convertir le type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult' en 'int?'"

Any Idea ?

Comment: You never call anything on your linq query.Try adding the following `.ToList().Count()` at the end of your linq query.

Comment: I want to use my sql count, my view is just a count, so a entity count is useless for me.

I juste want to get back the result of my sql count and un it in my application .

Comment: Is there any reason you want to do this, you could just as easily write the same query in linq?

Comment: Please post what the error is.  Makes it much easier to know how to fix it.

Comment: @mituw16 I dont want to use an entity without reason so I don't want to load my view and count it, 
I just want to use a stored procedure,

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution

```
int? myInt = ctx.nbrMail(DateTime.Now, new ObjectParameter("nbrDeMailDuJour", typeof(Int32))).FirstOrDefault();
```